# wordpress `"konsulting.zip"` theme is incompatible with the `modeltheme-framework` plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

If I install wordpress `"konsulting.zip"` theme and the required plugin, when I install the `modeltheme-framework` plugin I get this error:

> ( ! ) Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable in
>   C:\wamp\www\wp\wp-content\plugins\modeltheme-framework\init.php on
>   line 746

this is the  `init.php` file of my computer on `line 746`

```
// if it's an array of one, extract it
        elseif ( is_array( $meta_box['pages'] ) && count( $meta_box['pages'] === 1 ) )
            $type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ) ? end( $meta_box['pages'] ) : false;

        if ( !$type )
            return self::get_mb_type();
```

Answer (score 1):

In wp-content/plugins/modeltheme-framework/init.php, change line 746:

```
elseif ( is_array( $meta_box['pages'] ) && count( $meta_box['pages'] === 1 ) )
```

to...

```
elseif ( is_array( $meta_box['pages'] ) && count( $meta_box['pages'] ) === 1 )
```